# Run qsub on cluster via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, cluster

I'm setting up a system which automatically generates computing jobs on a local (Linux) machine, copies them to a cluster and submits them to the queuing system.

I try to avoid the need for scripts which run on the cluster (this way, there's only one script, and it runs where I can debug it).

I've got my `authorized_keys` set up, so after creating all the required files locally, I do this, from the local case directory:

```
ssh cluster 'mkdir /home/user/casedir'
scp localdir/* cluster:/home/user/casedir/
ssh cluster 'qsub /home/user/casedir/run_script.sge'
```

...this creates the case directory on the cluster, copies over all the files I need but then fails in the third line, saying:
    qsub: command not found

However, if I interactively type `ssh cluster` to get a shell on the cluster, then type the qsub command, it launches the job and runs just fine!

... what am I getting wrong here? The cluster is running a fairly old version of the Sun Grid Engine, in case that's relevant.

I guess I could locally produce and copy over a bash script which will execute the qsub command on the cluster but that seems like a very roundabout way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you have added `qsub` to your `$PATH` in the `.bashrc` or `.profile` files of your user on the cluster. Those are not read when executing a command via `ssh`.

It should work fine if you use the full path to `qsub`:

```
ssh cluster '/usr/local/bin/qsub /home/user/casedir/run_script.sge'
```

Obviously, you'll need to change `/usr/local/bin/qsub` to whatever the path of `qsub` is on your cluster. If you don't know it, log on to the cluster and run `type qsub`.

Comment: That's it! I had to add ``source /etc/bashr; source /etc/profile`` to the line, that does it! I also have to ``cd`` to the case directory before submitting, else all data lands in the root directory... Thanks a lot!